# MYSQL Multiple Group Concat

Tags: mysql, group-concat

Hi I have a table called Engineers and a table called Post_Codes

When I use the following sql I get a list of engineers and the postcodes associated with them by using the Group Concat statement but I cannot figure out how to also include in another Group Concat (if indeed I need one) to also list in another field called Secondary_Post_Codes_Assigned those post codes linked to the same engineer via the Secondary_Engineer_id field.

```
SELECT 
    Engineer.Engineer,GROUP_CONCAT(Post_Code SEPARATOR ', ') as Post_Codes_Assigned,
    Engineer.Region, 
    Engineer.active, 
    Engineer.Engineer_id
FROM Engineer INNER JOIN Post_Code ON Engineer.Engineer_id = Post_Code.Engineer_id 
GROUP BY Engineer_id
```

What I need is output similar to this.

```
Engineer_id | Post_Codes_Assigned | Secondary_Post_Codes_Assigned


----------
1           | AW, AW3             | B12                          |
2           | B12                 | AW, CV12                     |
```

I hope this is clear as I am pretty new to mysql.

Regards
Alan

Comment: Your current query already has several problems.  Can you show us sample data?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: Several problems? Which? Are you referring to the missing qualifier in `GROUP BY Engineer_id`? I must admit I don't see any others.

Comment: In general it's better to handle issues of data display in a presentation layer

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Look closely.  He is selecting non-aggregate columns which also do not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: The selected columns are functionally dependent on the Engineer_id, so this is perfect standard SQL. Many DBMS don't comply with the standard by not allowing this. (And MySQL doesn't, because it would also allow for non-dependent columns in the select clause.)

Answer (score 0):

You are already joining the primary post codes and list them, now do the same with the secondary ones.

```
SELECT 
  e.Engineer,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pc1.Post_Code) AS Primary_Post_Codes_Assigned,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pc2.Post_Code) AS Secondary_Post_Codes_Assigned,
  e.Region, 
  e.active, 
  e.Engineer_id
FROM Engineer e
JOIN Post_Code pc1 ON e.Engineer_id = pc1.Engineer_id 
JOIN Post_Code pc2 ON e.Engineer_id = pc2.Secondary_Engineer_id
GROUP BY e.Engineer_id;
```

As you see, you need `DISTINCT` because when selecting all primary and all secondary postcodes, you are getting rows for all combinations of them in the intermediate result. So you must get rid of duplicates. For this reason ist is better to aggregate before joining. (Which I generally consider a good idea, so you may want to make this a habit when working with aggregates.)

```
SELECT 
  e.Engineer,
  pc1.Post_Codes AS Primary_Post_Codes_Assigned,
  pc2.Post_Codes AS Secondary_Post_Codes_Assigned,
  e.Region, 
  e.active, 
  e.Engineer_id
FROM Engineer e
JOIN 
(
  SELECT Engineer_id, GROUP_CONCAT(Post_Code) AS Post_Codes
  FROM Post_Code
  GROUP BY Engineer_id
) pc1 ON e.Engineer_id = pc1.Engineer_id 
JOIN 
(
  SELECT Secondary_Engineer_id, GROUP_CONCAT(Post_Code) AS Post_Codes
  FROM Post_Code
  GROUP BY Secondary_Engineer_id
) pc2 ON e.Engineer_id = pc2.Secondary_Engineer_id;
```

A third option would be subqueries in the `SELECT` clause. I usually prefer them to be in the `FROM` clause as shown, because then it is easy to add more columns to the subqueries, which is not possible in the `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT 
  e.Engineer,
  (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(pc1.Post_Code)
    FROM Post_Code pc1
    WHERE pc1.Engineer_id = e.Engineer_id
  ) AS Primary_Post_Codes_Assigned,
  (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(pc2.Post_Code)
    FROM Post_Code pc2
    WHERE pc2.Secondary_Engineer_id = e.Engineer_id 
  ) AS Secondary_Post_Codes_Assigned,
  e.Region, 
  e.active, 
  e.Engineer_id
FROM Engineer e;
```

Comment: Thanks very much this is great.